# Easiest free tool to install that allows sending ssh command from dos batch file

Tags: ssh

Anyone knows which I should use with an example (for example unzipping a file) ?

I'm not asking for a SSH Windows Client by Command Line (I already have Tunnelier), I'm asking how to script ssh from DOS BATCH file.

Comment: Since you've already got your heart set on Tunnelier, you're going to need to read the docs on it. This solution is going to be specific to the application you are using and its capabilities.

Comment: Install a ssh client. Call that ssh client from within your BATCH file.

Comment: Doesn't this work? http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier#sexec

Comment: Great I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SSHWindows.SourceForge.Net](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) (emphasis mine):

> ### OpenSSH for Windows
>
> OpenSSH for Windows is a free package that installs a minimal OpenSSH server and **client** utilities in the Cygwin package without needing the full Cygwin installation.
>
> The OpenSSH for Windows package provides full SSH/SCP/SFTP support. **SSH terminal support provides a familiar Windows Command prompt**, while retaining Unix/Cygwin-style paths for SCP and SFTP.

Comment: If I need to install Cygwin ... I already use Tunnelier so that's not my question ;)

Comment: *without needing the full Cygwin installation*